# Data not being sent to plotly

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, plotly

I made an small script on my raspberryPI to get data from mongo and build a plotly graph and this week I had a system crash and needed to recover data from months ago...
The whole process was working with something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port';
var str = "";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db("DB");

var cursor = dbo.collection("ColectionA").find();
if (cursor == null) {
    console.log('cursor is null');
} else {
    console.log('cursor not null');
    var xArray = [];
    var yArray = [];
    cursor.each(function (err, item) {
        if (item != null) {
            xArray.push(item.item1);
            yArray.push(item.item2)
            console.log(item.item1 + ' ' + item.item2);
        } else {
            var plotly = require('plotly')("user", "APIkey");

            var data = [{
                x: xArray,
                y: yArray,
                type: "scatter"
            }];
            var layout = {
                title: "Title1",
                xaxis: {
                    title: "Date/Time",
                    rangemode: "nonnegative",
                    autorange: true,
                    titlefont: {
                        family: "Courier New, monospace",
                        size: 18,
                        color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    title: "Users",
                    rangemode: "nonnegative",
                    autorange: true,
                    titlefont: {
                        family: "Courier New, monospace",
                        size: 18,
                        color: "#7f7f7f"
                    }
                }
            };
            var graphOptions = {
                layout: layout,
                filename: "date-axes",
                fileopt: "overwrite"
            };
            plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function (err, msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            console.log(err);
            });

            dbo.close();
        }
    });
}
});
setTimeout(function() {
console.log('done...');
process.exit();
}, 20000);
```

Now I'm not sending any data back to plotly...
I even tried to send a smaller data array back to the graph, like

```
var data = [{x:[0,1,2], y:[3,2,1], type: 'scatter'}];
```

without success, tried npm install plotly thinking that the "crash" could have had influence on the process,
changed the APIkey on the dashboard and here...

All I get from the "plotly.plot" logs is "Done" msg...

So... no sucess... Any idea on what else can I use to debug?

Comment: Your shutting off the whole process after 20s. Is it possible that plotly might just take longer for whatever reason?

Comment: was working before but I'll try to increase that timer

Comment: Why is there a timer at all? Why not just wait and see, if your requests finish (with a result or an error)?

Comment: works without the timer but without it it seems to hang and cron doesn't load it... no idea why